# problems deploying bottle application with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bottle

newbie here--I've been trying to create a "Hello World" in bottle using google app engine. I got the "hello world" part to show up, but even on on index page, I get the following output: "Hello world!Status: 500"
If I try to add new routes (like the '/page' route), and I navigate to the new route, I get "Server error: The website encountered an error while retrieving... It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly." After I navigate to the improperly configured page, if I try to go back to '/', I will  also receive a server error. I have placed bottle.py in my root directory. Could someone please help me to configure my file properly? Thanks!

```
import bottle 
from bottle import route, template, request, error, debug

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

@route('/page')
def page():
    return 'page!'

bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(server='gae')
```

Comment: post the traceback of the actual error. if your getting these errors locally check your sdk output, if deployed check the error logs.

Comment: I have the same issue. When you use Python 2.7 and use multithreading then: A) if the handler is main.py: Fatal error when loading application configuration: threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: main.py B) if the handler is main: Status 500, 'module' is not callable C) if you set the handler to main.app and import bottle.app into the scope of handler, then: error calling app, invalid number of args

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good tutorial for bottle on GAE: http://blog.rutwick.com/use-bottle-python-framework-with-google-app-engine

DISCLAIMER: I did not run the tutorial, but it looks correct.

main.py:

```
from framework import bottle
from framework.bottle import route, template, request, error, debug
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

@route('/')
def DisplayForm():
    message = 'Hello World'
    output = template('templates/home', data = message)
    return output

def main():
    debug(True)
    run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())

@error(403)
def Error403(code):
    return 'Get your codes right dude, you caused some error!'

@error(404)
def Error404(code):
    return 'Stop cowboy, what are you trying to find?'

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

app.yaml:

```
application: my-bottle-app
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

As you see there, are a number of differences from your sample code. The tutorial does a good job of explaining them, so I won't go into detail here.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

app.yaml:

```
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

main.py:

```
import bottle

@bottle.route('/')
def root():
    return 'hello!'

bottle.run(server='gae', debug=True)
app = bottle.app()
```

Here's the original answer from GitHub.
https://github.com/defnull/bottle/issues/401

Answer (score 0):

When using WSGI like in the [App Engine + Bottle started code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-bottle-skeleton/archive/master.zip), you can call `bottle.debug()` when your code is running on the dev server:

```
import bottle
import os

DEBUG = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development')  
bottle.debug(DEBUG)
app = bottle.Bottle()
```

And in `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```