# How do I make bottle work with google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bottle

This is the code,

```
import webapp2
from framework import bottle
from framework.bottle import route, template, request, error, debug

@route('/')
def root():
         return 'hello world'
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
        root()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

All the dependencies are there (framework, bottle, etc), however, when I deploy it using GAE, I just get an empty page!

Also I tried these and none of them worked, perhaps GAE changed its settings:

- http://blog.rutwick.com/use-bottle-python-framework-with-google-app-engine
- [problems deploying bottle application with google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662972/problems-deploying-bottle-application-with-google-app-engine)

Comment: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#google-appengine has solid info on running Bottle in GAE

Answer (score 1):

You have not followed the advice in those links. Most obviously, you are simply calling `root` without actually returning its result back as the response. In Python, you need to explicitly use `return` to send a value back from a function, which you don't do in `get`.

You are also hopelessly confused with setting up the handlers. If you're using bottle, use it: there's no need to have webapp in the mix as well. Webapp is an alternative to bottle, not something that is baked into GAE. Your links show exactly how to do this.

Comment: I did actually follow their advice, and they didnt work, so i just came up with this code

Comment: "Didn't work" is not helpful. What happened when you followed that blog entry exactly?

Comment: I got an error saying that it couldnt resolve my request and that I should report for further assistance. The missing part in those blogs is they didnt initiate app(). Anyhow, I posted the answer which worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware to use:

```
app.run(server='gae')
```

Otherwise bottle will try to access your system and GAE will fail

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked perfectly for me: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-bottle-skeleton

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The `Bottle` class implements WSGI which works for GAE if you make it a global variable in your main script handler.

#### main.py

```py
from bottle import default_app, route, run

@route('/')
def root():
  return 'hello world'

app = default_app()
```

#### app.yaml

```yaml
runtime: python39

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

#### requirements.txt

```
bottle
```

And that's it!

I tested this on Google Cloud Shell with Bottle 0.12.19 and deploying to Google App Engine Standard.